# Making an inactive browser tab active again automatically using react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tabs

Im building a react app. in the app, Im receiving a message through an API and if I receive a message, the message automatically display to the user.

But the problem is if the user is on another tab, they cannot see whether a message is received. I want to make the react app tab active immediately if the user is browsing on another tab after receiving a message. Is there a way in react to make the tab automatically active?

Answer (score 1):

There is not.

The only solution I can think of is to create a push notification that could display the message to the user even if he is on another tab.

Intro to push notifications here:
https://www.studytonight.com/post/javascript-desktopbrowser-push-notification-example